# Prove the Inequality given below

Tags: inequality

> Let $a,b,c$ be positive real numbers such that $a+b+c=1$. Prove that $$
>  \frac a{a^2+b^3+c^3} + \frac b{a^3+b^2+c^3} + \frac c{a^3+b^3+c^2}\le\frac1{5abc}.$$

I tried using AM-GM-HM-QM inequality but had no luck.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! Please, format maths on this site using LaTeX, as described [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation). There is also a [quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proving the inequality $\sum_{\text{cyc}} \frac{a}{a^2+b^3+c^3}\le\frac1{5abc}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3442048/proving-the-inequality-sum-textcyc-fracaa2b3c3-le-frac15abc) – found instantly with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Cdfrac%20a%7Ba%5E2%2Bb%5E3%2Bc%5E3%7D%20%2B%5Cdfrac%20b%7Ba%5E3%2Bb%5E2%2Bc%5E3%7D%20%2B%5Cdfrac%20c%7Ba%5E3%2Bb%5E3%2Bc%5E2%7D%5Cle%20%5Cdfrac%201%7B5abc%7D%24&p=1)